# Search and replace with sed by both in pattern and line

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I went through lots of similar posts but none could be applied to mine.

I would like to search and replace using sed in some particular lines in a way that in only matches the **first occurrence**; lets say I have this part of the script:

```
processor  <- read.table("../mall_all/adpcm/FULL_DB-constprop", header=TRUE, colClasses=c("reassociate"="factor", "scalarrepl"="factor", "inline"="factor", "sccp"="factor", "loop_reduce"="factor"))

processor<-processor[-c(20:40)]

processor$intensity <- processor$int_high - processor$int_low
processor$performance<- processor$perf_high - processor$perf_low
processor<-processor[-c(1:4)]
processor<-processor[,!names(processor) %in% c("constprop")]
```

I want to keep changing the **$constprop** variable in

`"../mall_all/adpcm/FULL_DB-constprop"`

AND

```
[,!names(processor) %in% c("constprop")]
```

in a loop that I wrote, the problem is; I want the **colClasses parameteres** AND **the rest of the scripts** remains the same while entering the loop (the loop has the compiler options like: reassociate, inline, constprop, etc)

I was wondering why my search and replace didn't work :

```
set -x
compilerOptionList="constprop dce inline instcombine licm loop_reduce loop_rotate loop_unroll loop_unswitch loop_unswitch mem2reg memcpyopt reassociate scalarrepl sccp simplifycfg "

stringToBeReplaced=constprop

for compilerOption in $compilerOptionList
do
        echo "Using compiler option: $compilerOption"

        //here you could see  the sed scripts

        sed -i "1,15  /FULL_DB/,/header/ s/$stringToBeReplaced/$compilerOption/" r.scr
        stringToBeReplaced=$compilerOption
        make
        mv Rplots.pdf Rplots_adpcm_$compilerOption.pdf
        echo "DONE! $compilerOption"
done
```

Thanks all for your time and help ;)

Amir

Comment: Guys, I just figured out I could use two seds. i.e like this :   sed -i "2,3 s/$stringToBeReplaced/$compilerOption/" r.scr
        sed -i "9,11 s/$stringToBeReplaced/$compilerOption/" r.scr

Comment: But, anyways, Appreciated if I can use just one sed (i will learn sth new ;))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure having rightly understood your need, but maybe someting like

```
sed -e "
    1,15ba;
    /FULL_DB/,/header/ba;
    bb;
    :a;
    s/stringToBeReplaced/$compilerOption/;
    :b;
  " -i r.scr
```

could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This line is problematic

```
sed -i "1,15  /FULL_DB/,/header/ s/$stringToBeReplaced/$compilerOption/" r.scr
```

It's not a valid sed command syntax. You'll need to enclose part of it in braces like this

```
sed -i "1,15  { /FULL_DB/,/header/ s/$stringToBeReplaced/$compilerOption/ }" r.scr
```

---

But I think a tidier way is to use separate files for input and output of `sed`, i.e. change that line to

```
sed "1,15 s/constprop/$compilerOption/" r.scr_tmp >r.scr
```

You don't need the `stringToBeReplaced` variable. This way you always substitute "constprop", and don't have to worry that the string to be replaced appears elsewhere in the code.

`r.scr_tmp` would contain the same code as `r.scr` except that the `constprop` part of `r.scr_tmp`remains unchanged.